# Which version of assembly does OllyDbg disassemble binary to?

Tags: disassembly, assembly, disassemblers

So I understand that there are many assemblers such as MASM, FASM, NASM, etc.

But which version is the disassembler in OllyDbg and Cheat Engine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OllyDbg supports disassembling to MASM, IDEAL, and HLA:

[image: Debugging options]

Answer (score 2):

ollydbg 2.0 supports AT&T syntax also

```
CPU Disasm
Address   Command                                  Comments
01002C0C  CMPL    %ESI, %DS:notepad.fUntitled      ; Case 3 of switch notepad.1002BBE
01002C12  MOVL    %DS:notepad.g_ftOpenedAs, %EAX
01002C17  MOVL    %EAX, %DS:notepad.g_ftSaveAs
01002C1C  JNE     $notepad.01002C37
01002C1E  PUSHL   %ESI                             ; /Arg3 = 0B1F01
01002C1F  PUSHL   $OFFSET notepad.szFileName       ; |Arg2 = notepad.szFileName
01002C24  PUSHL   %DS:notepad.hwndNP               ; |Arg1 = 0
01002C2A  CALL    $notepad.SaveFile                ; \notepad.SaveFile
```